# Key-Value map instead of a very long ELSE-IF construction?

Tags: java, string

I am currently working on a method that is mapping some strings to other strings.

It has a LOT of values, and the method starts to look like this:

The method ValueHelper.isEqual() is looking for an exact match.

```
private IValue1 mapValue(IValue2 value2) {
    if (ValueHelper.isEqual(value2.getName(), StatusValues.ACTIVE)) {
            return ValueHelper.getName(StatusValues2.WORKING);
    } else if (ValueHelper.isEqual(value2.getName(), StatusValues.INACTIVE)) {
            return ValueHelper.getName(StatusValues2.NOT_WORKING);
    } else if (ValueHelper.isEqual(value2.getName(), StatusValues.IN_SERVICE)) {
            return ValueHelper.getName(StatusValues2.SERVICE);
    }
}
```

At current point I have 10 else-if code blocks.

What is the best way to make this method simpler and shorter? Extracting the values to a Key-Value map? Or maybe another option?

Comment: Using Map<key, value> is wise choice. If your process become more complicate, try to use interface for better maintenance.

Comment: Depends on what `ValueHelper.isEqual` does...

Answer (score 2):

A map would do fine I guess. You could also think about switch-case to make it a little less verbose:

```
private IValue1 mapValue(IValue2 value2) {
 switch(value2.getName()) {
     case StatusValues.ACTIVE:     return StatusValues2.WORKING;
     case StatusValues.INACTIVE:   return StatusValues2.NOT_WORKING;
     case StatusValues.IN_SERVICE: return StatusValues2.SERVICE;
     default: throw new RuntimeException();
 }
```

Comment: You are assuming `ValueHelper.isEqual()` looks for exact matches. May not be true.

Comment: The isEqual() method looks for exact matches ;)

Comment: Then I'd say the method above should work just fine (unless *getName()* can return null, in which case you would need check that case first).

Comment: Yes. You'd need to do null check (if you expect null values). Also the return is missing call to `ValueHelper.getName()` which can be done inside/outside of the `swicth-case`. In general, I think what OP is looking for is Java-implementation for Data Mapper pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The OOP approach is to have this method in your interface `IValue2`:

```
interface IValue2 {
    ...
    String getName();
    IValue1 mapValue();
}
```

Each implementing object now must override this abstract method. This maybe requires some implementation changes. You could - for example - have a `ActiveValue2` class:

```
class ActiveValue2 implements IValue2 {
    ...
    public String getName() {
        return StatusValues.ACTIVE;
    }
    public IValue1 mapValue() {
        return ValueHelper.getName(StatusValues2.WORKING);
    }
}
```

You now simply call the `mapValue` method on an `IValue2`-types variable. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, having a Map of `<StatusValues, StatusValues2>` would be the right approach.

You will simply look for the current `StatusValue` as the key and receive the matching `StatusValue2`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider converting your strings to an enum:

```
public enum Status {
    ACTIVE("active", WORKING),
    INACTIVE("inactive", NOT_WORKING),
    IN_SERVICE("inservice", SERVICE),
    ...

    private final String name;
    private final Value value;

    Status(String name, Value value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Optional<Value> getValueForName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(v -> isEqual(name, this.name))
            .findAny();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use guava Immutable Map. They are faster and take less memory than standard java HashMap.

Comment: How are they faster and take less memory than say a standard HashMap?